# How to configure Airflow RBAC UI Security with REMOTE_USER

Tags: security, user-interface, airflow

Am trying to configure the latest ariflow 1.10.10 with the new RBAC UI, wanted it to be single sign on.

tried the DB/LDAP options but this required user id/password to login.
trying to set up REMOTE_USER but not able to find good documentation or examples on how get it working.
enabled the below setting the airflow_webserver.cnfg file

AUTH_TYPE= AUTH_REMOTE_USER

and enabled kerberos in core section on airflow.cnfg file, when restarted the webserver it gives the below error

{decorators.py:113} WARNING - Access is Denied for: can_index on: Airflow

need help to resolve this .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I first tried to access the UI without logging in (i.e. as a Public user), I got the `{decorators.py:113} WARNING - Access is Denied for: can_index on: Airflow`. Adding `can_index` to Public role should allow the UI to load so you can then log in. I'm unfamiliar with using a REMOTE_USER, but I imagine adding similar permissions to a role and assigning it to the REMOTE_USER would help.